# how to trigger azure acr task to build app image from change in tag of base image

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

I followed this tutorial, [container-registry-tutorial-base-image-update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-base-image-update). I would like to adapt it into my current workflow. However, I want the `Dockerfile-app` to automatically build if there is a change in the base image tag, i.e. `FROM ${REGISTRY_NAME}/baseimages/pyapp:${TAG}`

I was thinking just put an environmental var in the base image Dockerfile, `Dockerfile-base` like `ENV TAG v2`, but how would that get passed to the `Dockerfile-app`? I'm probably not understanding something. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you see the `Dockerfile-app` set the option ARG REGISTRY_NAME at the beginning and then use the ARG as:

```
FROM ${REGISTRY_NAME}/baseimages/node:15-alpine
```

And then you need to use the Azure CLI command to create the task like this:

```
az acr task create \
    --registry $ACR_NAME \
    --name baseexample1 \
    --image helloworld:{{.Run.ID}} \
    --arg REGISTRY_NAME=$ACR_NAME.azurecr.io \
    --context https://github.com/$GIT_USER/acr-build-helloworld-node.git \
    --file Dockerfile-app \
    --git-access-token $GIT_PAT
```

This command uses the parameter `--arg` to pass the ARG REGISTRY_NAME into the `Dockerfile-app` file, not the environment variables.

If you want to use `FROM ${REGISTRY_NAME}/baseimages/pyapp:${TAG}` in the `Dockerfile-app`, then you need to set two ARG in the file:

```
ARG REGISTRY_NAME
ARG TAG
```

And add the two args in the CLI command:

```
--arg REGISTRY_NAME=$ACR_NAME.azurecr.io \
--arg TAG=your_tag
```

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion, is it possible that the `Dockerfile-app` can be triggered also when I build on local machine, not using azure cli? for example, if i do a git commit and push just on the `Dockerfile-app` file locally, will it auto build too? if it does, how can the `TAG` env var get passed to it?

Comment: @SpencerTrinh If you do not use the ACR task, then there is no task to build the image for you. It's the ACR task to trigger to build the images for you. Git command only pushes the changes to Github, then nothing more.

Comment: i was able to get a build from a git commit/push by passing the git repo url in `context`. it then triggered a build on the `Dockerfile-app` file. so was wondering if i can get both; trigger on git push to `Dockerfile-app` and trigger on change in `Dockerfile-base`

Comment: @SpencerTrinh If you use the Azure CLI to create the ACR task to trigger the build, then you can create the trigger base on the Dockerfile-base as the same as the Dockerfile-app.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh Do still work on this question? And if you already solve it?

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, I just create a new acr task that is based on the `Dockerfile-base` file right?

Comment: @SpencerTrinh If you want to trigger the build from the change of the Dockerfile-base file, it means it.